# Making button dissapear AFTER data is submitted

Tags: javascript, php

So I have this code:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function hidenow(id) {
        var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
         var button = document.getElementById("hidebutton");

        if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
                divelement.style.display ='block',
                button.style.display = "block";
        else
                divelement.style.display = 'none',
                button.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

And two buttons:

```
<p>Programma's waarop u kunt abonneren:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td id="hideit" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <?php
                 echo $alreadysub; echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam );
                 ?>
                 </td>
                <th>
                <button id="hidebutton" style="display:block" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

```
<!-- Dit stuk code laat de programma's zien waar de radiostation al op geabonneerd is. -->
<br> 
<p>De programma's waarop u geabonneerd bent:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programmatest_action', 'set_programmatest' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programmatest" type="submit" id="button" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?>">Abonnement opzeggen</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

At the moment, when I click a button; it dissapears. But it comes back as soon as the data is submitted to the database and the page is refreshed. I want the button (along with the program that comes with it) to dissapear. I already tried making a `isset`. But this results in BOTH buttons dissapearing and not just one.

Example:

[image]

This is the first button, it is written in the second piece of code. When I click one button, it needs to dissapear along with the program. I tried doing this using `isset` but it resulted in the button dissapearing all together (both).

I also have this button:

[image]

I have done nothing to this button, since I do not want it.

I have tried looking on Stack Overflow and several articles and youtube videos. I have been busy making this for a week but I do not know how to make it work.

How can I make sure that the first button is not shown even after the data is submitted in the db or after the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault ?

This stops the page from refreshing.

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: Yh, but if I revisit the page it is displayed again. It should not be displayed when in db. Yes I tried the article

Comment: Misunderstood your question, also the answer from @adeel-tahir should be what you are looking for. If you want the button to hide only for the user that submited you can use LocalStorage/SessionStorage, if you want to hide it for everyone you need to query the db

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some condition which checks whether to display button or not.
After submitting form you can set localStorage data and in your logic first check for this localStorage, if it is set do not display button otherwise display them.
This way if someone also refreshes page the localStorage will not loose and your button will not display.You can reset localStorage through your code to display them again.

Otherwise you can do on page load check for data / value in database, if it exist do not display the button otherwise display them.

Comment: could you give a example?

Comment: Here is the example, hope this is what you are looking.View the source for code, you can also use jQuery if you want.

https://adeeltahir.me/examples/local_storage.html

Comment: your a hero, this is exactly what Im looking for.

Comment: Hi Adeel, apparently. This code disables me to be able to subscribe to a program. The code also does not work on the button underneath it. Which is added because of a foreach. Do you know how I can solve this? You can also look up my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656566/subscription-system-not-working-after-clicking-button

Comment: Thank you so much @AdeelTahir. I only have one last question. Could you please help me out with this one? I have another button with the exact same id I use for the other button. It really is just one button but since they are in a ````foreach```` they will be shown twice. However, when I click on this button, it will not dissapear. It is the button with the id ````some_id````