# Subscription system not working after clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following code:

Button:

```
<br>
<p>Programma's waarop u kunt abonneren:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="return processForm();">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td id="hideit" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <?php
                 echo $alreadysub; echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam );
                 ?>
                 </td>
                <th>
                <div><button id="some_id" style="display:block" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var divelement = document.getElementById("some_id");
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("form_submitted")){
        divelement.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        //Local Storage Not Set
    }
});

function processForm(){
    //Send Ajax to submit data and after its response set the local Storage
    divelement.style.display = 'none';
    //Set
    localStorage.setItem("form_submitted", 1);
    return false; //this will prevent form from submitting and refreshing the page.
}
```

Once the user clicks a button, he/she is subscribing to a program. To allow the user to subscribe to a program, I created the following code:

```
if (isset( $_POST['programma'] ) && isset( $_POST['set_programma'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['set_programma'], 'set_programma_action' )) {

    $data = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'programma', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( $current_user_id && ! empty( $data ) ) {
        //voeg de huidige user_id en data toe in de rij met meta_key programma
        $addprog = add_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $data );
        echo "U bent geabonneerd op". ' ' . $data;
    }
}
?>
```

I created the Javascript code to make sure that once the user is subscribed to a program, the button he clicked on along with the program dissapear. The only problem I have is that the user is not able to subscribe to a program anymore. The program is also not saved in the database. I have searched for several youtube videos on the issue but I cannot find a solution.

Also, for some reason, only the top button dissapears when clicked on. Not the buttom.

I am trying to put the button and the element inside of it in none display as soon as it is pressed. See image down here for the 2 buttons.

[image]

Comment: Change return false to return true in processForm() function.I was expecting you will put your logic here but because there is return false, therefore it is not allowing form to submit.

Comment: Thank you so much @AdeelTahir. I only have one last question. Could you please help me out with this one? I have another button with the exact same id I use for the other button. It really is just one button but since they are in a ````foreach```` they will be shown twice. However, when I click on this button, it will not dissapear. It is the button with the id ````some_id````

Comment: Oh i am afraid @Parsa_237 you can not have same ID on different element.
IDs should not be repeated, you can change them to class to achieve your result but remember this way all of your button having that class will hide.If this is you want it will work otherwise you need to modify existing code to achieve result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you want all the button to hide when form is submitted.For this you have to use class instead of id.

```
var divelement = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");

function hideByClass(){
    for(var i = 0; i < divelement.length; i++){
                divelement[i].style.display = "none";
            }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("form_submitted")){
         hideByClass();
    }else{
        //Local Storage Not Set
    }
});


function processForm(){
    //Send Ajax to submit data and after its response set the local Storage
    hideByClass();
    //Set
    localStorage.setItem("form_submitted", 1);
    return true;
}
```

And use class instead of id.You also have to use class on td as it is also in loop so id should not repeat.

```
<div><button class="some_class" style="display:block" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button></div>
```

Comment: Hi Adeel. Thank you so much for the answer that you posted. I really appreciate it. Unfortunatly, both buttons are not visible. I tried returning false but that does not work. Do you know how this can be solved. Please take your time to answer.

Comment: I want to confirm because you are using loop so it is displaying multiple td and buttons, after submitting form do you want those all buttons to be hidden or the one which is clicked?

Comment: Yes, only the ones who are clicked have to be hidden. I tried doing that but it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2**

If you want only clicked one to be hidden.For this you need to do modifications.Here are the modifications.

- Remove **onSubmit** from form.
- Add **Id** to form.
- Add a **counter** variable before starting loop also increment its value inside loop body. This is for making unique ids.
- Concatenate this counter variable in id for td and button.
- Change button type from submit to **button**.
- Call **processForm** function on button click with passed value of counter to identify which button is clicked.

**HTML / PHP**

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php 
        $counter=0; 
        foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Programma:</th>
            <td id="hideit<?php echo $counter;?>" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <?php
             echo $alreadysub; echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam );
             ?>
             </td>
            <th>
            <div><button id="some_id<?php echo $counter;?>" style="display:block" name="programma" type="button" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>" onClick="processForm(<?php echo $counter;?>);">Abonneer</button></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $counter++;
            } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function processForm(counter){
    //Send Ajax to submit data and after its response set the local Storage
    document.getElementById("hideit"+counter).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("some_id"+counter).style.display = 'none';

    //Set
    localStorage.setItem("form_submitted", 1);
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi Adeel. thank you so much for your answer. Without your help I would not have come this far. I am currently reading a few articles and trying some stuff. It is almost working. The element inside of it is also not displayed now which is good. I am only facing a few problems I am trying to solve. The field is not permanently not displayed and I cannot submit anymore. I am also not able to put the button underneath it in none displayed. Since there are two buttons. I do not want to put pressure on you and I feel ashamed that I asked so much of you. If you could, in your own time, help me out.

Comment: UPDATE: Hi Adeel, the button underneath it also works now. My only problem is that the button and element I click are not permanently on non-display and that I cannot submit anymore.

Comment: Could you please help me out with this last problem?

Comment: @Parsa_237 i did not get your last question.I would suggest as conversation is becoming too lengthy so we can discuss personally through chat and i try to figure and solve your issues.

Comment: Hi Adeel, I am unable to add you in the chat. Are you able to make a chat and invite me in it?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213414/subscription-button . This is the link to the chat Adeel. Could you please join it?